# Inclusion $H^1_0(\Omega)\cap C^k(\Omega)\subset C^0(\overline\Omega)$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset {\bf R}^d$ be a bounded domain with a Lipschitz boundary. Assume that a function $u$ is $C^k$ *inside* $\Omega$ and that $u$ also belongs to $H^1_0(\Omega)$. Can one conclude that $u$ is continuous on the closure $\overline{\Omega}$? (If necessary, one can assume $k=\infty$.)

Comment: The answer is no. If I will find time I will write more details tomorrow.

Comment: $u=z/r$ (multiplied by a cut-off), $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ for $z>0$ is a counterexample  since  continuity at 0 fails.